# Posting to a REST endpoint from a vm queue in Mule

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, esb, mule

I have a mule flow which accepts an xml and posts it to a vm queue names as "mailQueue" in mule. The xml input and mule flow are below:

```
<Mail>
  <Name>JonHender</Name>
  <Age>16</Age>
</Mail>
```

---

Mule_config.xml:

```
 <!-- This is the persistent VM connector -->
           <vm:connector name="mailQueueConnector" queueTimeout="1000">
                 <vm:queue-profile>
                <file-queue-store />
                 </vm:queue-profile>
           </vm:connector>


            <flow name="MailService">
                <https:inbound-endpoint address="https://localhost:71234/message/email"
                    method="POST"
                    exchange-pattern="request-response"
                    contentType="application/xml"/>

                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="mailQueue" connector-ref="mailQueueConnector">
                    <message-property-filter pattern="http.status=200" />
                    <logger message="INTO mailQueue" level="INFO"/>
                </vm:outbound-endpoint>

            </flow>
```

Now, I have to read from this "mailQueue" and post it to a REST end point(https://localhost:71234/messages/sendemail). I tried by adding this in the same flow, but did not work

```
<inbound>
    <vm:inbound-endpoint address="vm://emailBufferQueue" exchange-pattern="one-way" connector-ref="emailQueueConnector" />
</inbound>
<outbound>
    <https:outbound-endpoint address="https://localhost:71234/messages/sendemail"
</outbound>
```

How do I read from the vm queue and post it to a REST end point? Can I do it in the same flow in which iam writing to the queue or should I be creating a new flow? Can somebody show me the flow to read from the and send it to Rest end point?

Advance Thanks and Merry Christmas Y'all

Comment: Hey David...I am not completly familiar with the rules of this forum. It's my bad and will keep it in mind next time. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consume the `mailQueue` in another flow:

```
<flow name="MailSender">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="mailQueue"
                         exchange-pattern="one-way"
                         connector-ref="mailQueueConnector" />
    <https:outbound-endpoint
           address="https://#[message.inboundProperties.username]:#[message.inboundProperties.password]@localhost:71234/messages/sendemail" />
</flow>
```

Comment: btw, i started to read your "mule in action" book yesterday. Great book so far...Any Idea on if there is any updated edition coming up?

Comment: Thanks. I do hope you bought the second edition (covers Mule 3): http://manning.com/dossot2/ We have new chapters coming every month or so.

Comment: while posting the message in the "mailQueue" to the REST endpoint, i get this exception..        Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint https://localhost:71234/v1. Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream (org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException)
  org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter:160 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/security/UnauthorisedException.html)

Comment: how can I pass in the authentication details needed for the Rest end point to the message in the queue?

Comment: As message properties - then use these properties in the outbound endpoint URL to authenticate the call.

Comment: I've added an example above.

Comment: Thanks for the help David...Will test it out ASAP.have to run home to avoid a snow strom now....Merry Christmas if I don't see you again...thanks again for all the help..